# A return in a while loop vs a break

Tags: java, while-loop, return

Consider a code :

Two return statements, one in while loop and the other out of while loop. No break

```
while (node != null) {
   if (node.item == 5) {
      return node;
   }
   node = node.next;
}
return node;
```

A single return with a break in a while loop.

```
while (node != null) {
   if (node.item == 5) {
      break;
   }
   node = node.next;
}
return node;
```

Is there any strong argument to follow a particular method over the other ?

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/142144/whiletrue-and-loop-breaking-anti-pattern

Comment: No right/wrong answer - it'll just be opinions. That being said, my first quick glance at your `return` version made me think "but now that second return outside the  loop is pointless/redundant"... then I blinked and looked again. So I'd personally go with the `break` version

Comment: This isn't really the sort of question works on Stack Overflow as it doesn't have one answer and encourages discussion (ie. noise). Both approaches have their merits.

Comment: While I agree with the comments that this is a style issue, in this particular case one could rewrite the code to avoid the "problem".  e.g.  `while ((node != null) && (node.item != 5)) node = node.next;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first will only work if the sole purpose of the method is to find the matching node. If you want to do something with that node outside of the while loop but within the same method, you'll need to use the second approach.

That said, I prefer the first approach and would argue that the Single Responsibility Principle would encourage you to make a method specifically for getting out the matching node.

I would `return null` at the end, though, so that it's easier for a reader to understand that that's effectively what you'd be returning if you ever get to the end of the method.

Comment: Very good point about `return null`.